# Why is my Android Studio project thinking I want to use API 13 and not 26?

Tags: android, xml

So, I am building an app in Android Studio and I am having some trouble with justifying my text in XML. I know that there is `android:justificationMode="inter_word"` for API > 26 and thats really what I would like to use. However, if I use that property in my XML file it doesn't work. I've already tried to build a different project but the result is the same.

A couple days ago I mistakely used a property that doesnt really exist and the Android studio presented me the following error:

```
Android resource linking failed
com.example.appl.app-mergeDebugResources-40:/layout-sw360dp-v13/cd.xml:29: error: 'ended' is incompatible with attribute gravity (attr) flags [bottom=80, center=17, center_horizontal=1, center_vertical=16, clip_horizontal=8, clip_vertical=128, end=8388613, fill=119, fill_horizontal=7, fill_vertical=112, left=3, right=5, start=8388611, top=48].
error: failed linking file resources.
```

By observing the above error I see that there was a problem in my `layout-sw360dp-v13/cd.xml` however, if I go to the project folder I see no folder called `layout-sw360dp-v13`, only  `layout-sw360dp`. Does this mean that the project is somehow thinking that I want to use API 13 despite my minSDK being 26? Below you can find my gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appl"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.10'
}
```

I'm pretty new to developing applications so any help would be really appreciated. Also, I doubt the error is in my XML file code since I already tried to do a new project with different XML files and still have the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done for compatibility reasons because `sw<N>dp` qualifier was added only in api level 13. To quote [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#table2) (right after the very long table):

> Some configuration qualifiers have been added since Android 1.0, so not all versions of Android support all the qualifiers. Using a new qualifier implicitly adds the platform version qualifier so that older devices are sure to ignore it. For example, using a w600dp qualifier automatically includes the v13 qualifier, because the available-width qualifier was new in API level 13.

This way if the app was ever run on a device with an earlier api level, then all resources with `sw<N>dp` qualifier would automatically get filtered out and not confuse the OS that knows nothing about it. That happens in the first step in the flow chart included [in the same docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#BestMatch).